# Create own customed URL shortener

Tags: asp.net, url-shortener

I am currently trying to code out a simple asp.net URL shortener which allows me to customise the shortened url. I am also not allowed to use open source, which means I cannot use any of the url shortening services. I am required to develop on on my own.

But this is the first time I am doing this so i have no idea on how to start(excluding the UI).

I understand that there are already such questions being asked. But I've read through the posts and I couldn't understand what is it about. I've also tried to google for the solution but it doesn't seem to be working.

I would really appreciate any help given to me.

P.S I am fairly new in programming and not strong in any of the programming languages.

Comment: try to check : http://sourceforge.net/projects/shorturl-dotnet/

Comment: i've tried that link but when i try to run the project there is some problems

Comment: okay, try to learn basic things in programming, the sourceforge thingy that i shared is the simplest way to do what you want, with some or may be a lot of costumization

Comment: @qU3st: if you have some problems, you need to be asking Stackoverflow about your specific problems - rather than asking for help with an entire project.

Answer (score 5):

You would need:

- A system to store pairs of shortened URLs and their full version.
- A page which takes the shortened URL parameter (eg. `short.aspx?q=SHORTENED`), looks it up in your data store, and redirects to the full URL.
- Some interface to edit your data store, add new URLs, etcetera.

That should be it really. If this is too difficult, it might be smarter to start on a basic programming course first.

Comment: Thanks this helps. That means I am also required to have my owned short url. For example, www.hi.lol, as the shortened url?

Comment: Yes you should have a place to host the service/website, preferably one with a short name, otherwise it kind of defeats the point.

Comment: So in terms of the codes how is it done? Is there any example that gives a good tutorial? P.s Although u said that its better to start on basic programming course but currently that is my project for my course.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not for solving your homework questions like this. Build something first, and ask when you have a specific programming problem instead.